Extract variables from function and what environments they come from in R?
Wider context:
I would like to create a function that lists all the variables from the body of the specified function and prints out what environment it comes from.
Below is an example of the function with variables from the new environments.
g2 <- function() {
  print(cc)
  print(dd)
  print(ee)
}

e <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
e$cc <- "Hello from the new environment"
e$dd <- "Hello from the new environment2"
environment(g2) <- e
e2 <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
e2$dd <- "Hello from the new environment"
e2$ee <- "Hello from the new environment2"
environment(g2) <- e2

I have already reached the point where I store all the variables in a vector: symbols <- c("cc","dd","ee"), used environments in a second vector: envirs <- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) is.environment(get(x)))] and checking which environment the variable came from: xin <- sapply(envirs, function(x) sapply(symbols, function(y) exists(y,get(x)))).
And it looks like this:
> xin
       e    e2
cc  TRUE FALSE
dd  TRUE  TRUE
ee FALSE  TRUE

and
> e
<environment: 0x00000127b2a1e1a8>
> e2
<environment: 0x00000127b2a20988>

Now I would like it to look like this:
  Symbol            Definition
1     cc <environment: 0x00000127b2a1e1a8>
2     dd <environment: 0x00000127b2a1e1a8>, <environment: 0x00000127b2a20988>
3     ee <environment: 0x00000127b2a20988>

But I don't know how to get it when xin is in this form. When I check only one symbol e.g. “dd” in all environments then I manage to get this result:
xin <- sapply(envirs, function(x) exists("dd",get(x)))
l <- sapply(envirs[xin], function(x) get(x))
data.frame(t(sapply(l,c)))
                                  e                                e2
1 <environment: 0x00000127b2a1e1a8> <environment: 0x00000127b2a20988>

I am committed to solving this exclusively with the base package!, but I am also open to other solutions.

I know i am not answering the question, but i am curious about the applicability of this function, what are you trying to achieve?

This is just an extension of an academic task I encountered. The whole function lists all the symbols and determines their origin (what package they are from, environment, whether they are local variables, etc.). I just stopped at the problem of determining what environment a variable comes from, and the answer must be written in the format I gave in the question.

Assume that the problem is that given a list of environments, envirs,  that we wish to create a data frame whose first columns is the unique names in those environments sorted and whose second column is a list whose components are lists of the environments containing the object name for that row.
# sorted char vector of unique symbol names
symbols <- envirs |> lapply(ls) |> unlist() |> unique() |> sort()

# given symbol name s get environments containing it
getEnvs <- function(s) Filter(function(e) s %in% ls(e), envirs)

data <- data.frame(symbols, envirs = I(lapply(symbols, getEnvs)))
str(data)

giving
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ symbols: chr  "cc" "dd" "ee"
 $ envirs :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :<environment: 0x0000011e5fa93b88> 
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ :<environment: 0x0000011e5fa93b88> 
  .. ..$ :<environment: 0x0000011e5faa6880> 
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :<environment: 0x0000011e5faa6880> 
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"

If what is wanted is a character vector for the envirs column then use this instead:
getEnvs <- function(s) Filter(function(e) s %in% ls(e), envirs) |>
  sapply(capture.output) |>
  toString()

data <- data.frame(symbols, envirs = sapply(symbols, getEnvs))

Note
Set up input envirs
e <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
e$cc <- "Hello from the new environment"
e$dd <- "Hello from the new environment2"

e2 <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
e2$dd <- "Hello from the new environment"
e2$ee <- "Hello from the new environment2"

envirs <- list(e, e2)


You correctly solved the task, however, the result should be presented in the form as I showed in the question. In your solution, the envirs column is collapsed for the reason that they are lists. I wonder if there is a possibility to merge what is in the lists as it is done by e.g. paste?

The question is ambiguous on that account. To me it looks like it is asking for a list of lists but if the intention is to ask for a character vector as the envirs column then use the alternate code I have now provided at the end.
